# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мышкой на элемент, его цвет менялся случайным образом каждый раз?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мышкой на элемент, его цвет менялся случайным образом каждый раз?

Answer (score 8):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }
    
    $('div').mouseenter(function(e){
        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
    });
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator) на функцию `getRandomColor()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.hot').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    this.style.backgroundPositionX = (Math.random() * 100 | 0) + '%';
  });
});
```

```css
.hot {
  border: 1px dashed Gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 7000% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000, #FFA500, #FFFF00, #008000, #0000FF, #000080, #800080);
  transition: background-position 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hot" style=""></div>
```